windows 11 wake incomplete
Windows 11 insider edition, HP Laptop. It wakes up the screen and keyboard ok.
I expect a key press or mouse click to allow me to enter my pin number.
The login background is displayed correctly. The mouse moves but no presses or clicks have an effect. I see no menu bar, no windows, no controls to give any command. Alt-tab doesn't work.
The screen will time out and go black. A key press or mouse click will wake the screen then I am stuck again.
I need to A) login somehow or reboot then B) diagnose why this started today then C) implement a work around so I can fix it next time.

there is no clock displayed like usual. windows key did nothing. I will perhaps get ssh ready for next time.

power key press did sleep and wake but no changes. aha! five seconds holding down power shut it down. I logged in! progress!

I disabled "Fast Startup" as a precaution.
